# Como pasar un ID(nroEmpleado) a mi controlador para consultar datos de un usuario en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buen día compañeros, basicamente lo que quiero hacer es cuando el administrador de click en dl boton PDF exporte esos datos (esa parte de la logica ya esta) pero ahora como puedo enviar ese ID en este caso es un `nroEmpleado`

Desde la vista esta es la manera en la que mando llamar a función en el controlador para que imprima el PDF

```
 <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" href="'.site_url("solicitud/exportarpdf/1/".$key->nroEmpleado).'"><i class="icon-remove"></i>PDF</a>
```

ese `$key->nroEmpleado` como lo puedo pasar al controlador para que pueda filtrar correctamente los datos para cada usuario

Este es mi controlador

```
function exportarpdf($nroEmpleado = NULL) // Se podria recibir por esta parte? como?
    {
        ob_start();
        ini_set('memory_limit', '4098M');
        $this->load->library('fpdf181/fpdf');
        $this->load->model('solicitud_model');
        $this->load->model('user');
        $data['template'] = 'print_solicitudes';
        //$data["solicitud"] = $this->solicitud_model->getNroEmpleado(NULL);
        $registros = $this->solicitud_model->getSolicitud1("altas", NULL, NULL, NULL, 2689);
        print_r($registros);
        //die();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo la razón del `1` en la url `...exportarpdf/1/".$key->...` ya que la función `exportarpdf()` solo recibe un parámetro, para que funcione elimina ese `1` de la url y puedes declarar la función como `exportarpdf($nroEmpleado = false)` en el controlador.

Comment: Parece que funciona, si quiero solo acceder a un registro digase el email? tendria que hacer un foreach e insertarlos en un array?

Comment: Disculpa, desconozco tu estructura de datos pero imagino que lo obtienes con la función `getSolicitud1()`, si lo que obtienes es una fila, lo podrías hacer solo con `$registros['email']`, pero si lo que obtienes es una tabla tendrías que hacer un `foreach`.

Comment: obtengo un array con todos los datos, intentare del modo que me haz puesto

Comment: @the-breaker Tu respuesta me funciono bastante bien, puedes ponerla como tal

Comment: no hay problema, si gustas puedes publicarla, luego paso a votarte positivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las modificaciones que hice fueron en el enlace

Este

```
<a target="_blank" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" href="'.site_url("solicitud/exportarpdf/1/".$key->nroEmpleado).'"><i class="icon-remove"></i>PDF</a>
```

Por este

```
 <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning" href="'.site_url("solicitud/exportarpdf/".$key->nroEmpleado).'"><i class="icon-remove"></i>PDF</a>
```

y en el controlador de este modo quedo

```
 $this->load->library('fpdf181/fpdf');
        $this->load->model('solicitud_model');
        $this->load->model('user');
        $data['template'] = 'print_solicitudes';
        //$data["solicitud"] = $this->solicitud_model->getNroEmpleado(NULL);
        $registros = $this->solicitud_model->getSolicitud1("altas", NULL, NULL, NULL, $nroEmpleado);
```